# Getting Tumblr's API to work in ruby

Tags: ruby, api, tumblr

Can't seem to get Tumblr's API working. I'm trying to use the tumblife gem. I took a look at the source and I think these are the equivalent calls it's trying to make:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(app_key, app_secret, site: 'http://api.tumblr.com/')
access_token = OAuth.AccessToken.new(consumer, oauth_key, oauth_secret)
access_token.post('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/dashboard')
```

which returns a not authorized error. any help?